# Insert an inline image within a WPF TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-3.5, textblock

I have below WPF TextBlock within a border:

```
<Border Visibility="{Binding Path=BlinkOn, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red" CornerRadius="5" Margin="5">                    
    <TextBlock x:Name="lblStoryboard"
               TextAlignment="Center"
               Padding="5"                                                         
               Width="Auto"    
               Background="Red"
               Foreground="Black"
               FontSize="12.5"
               FontWeight="Bold"
               Style="{StaticResource BlinkingTextBlock}"
               Text="Hi there!" 
               TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"
               Visibility="{Binding Path=BlinkOn, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
    </TextBlock>
</Border>
```

Now I am trying to insert an inline image in front of the Textblock text, I mean, to the left (left side) of the TextBlock text and in the same line. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Stackpanel` with `Horizontal` `Orientation`.

*I have removed the binding since it as nothing to do with Adding image.*

```
 <Border   BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red" CornerRadius="5" Margin="5">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,-1">
            <Image Source="C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\WpfApp4\WpfApp4\Koala.jpg" Margin="0,459,0,0"  />
            <TextBlock x:Name="lblStoryboard"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           TextAlignment="Center"
           Padding="5"                                                         
           Width="Auto"    
           Background="Red"
           Foreground="Black"
           FontSize="12.5"
           FontWeight="Bold"

           Text="Hi there!" 
           TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Margin="0,459,0,0"
        />
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
```

[image]

Comment: @user1624552 is this what you are looking for ?